# Why does these 2 similar for loop have different results when adding ActionListener into JButton?

Tags: java, for-loop, jbutton

Originally I have a `JFrame` have 3 buttons: which button 0 prints 0 when clicked, button 1 prints 1 and so on:

```
JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    final int j=i;
    JButton jbutton=new JButton(""+j);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(jbutton);
    jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println(""+j);
        }
    });
}
jframe.setVisible(true);
jframe.pack();
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I want to reduce 1 line due to the final variable, and hence refactor the for-loop as this:

```
JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
for(final int[] arr={0};arr[0]<3;arr[0]++){
    JButton jbutton=new JButton(""+arr[0]);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(jbutton);
    jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println(""+arr[0]);
        }
    });
}
jframe.setVisible(true);
jframe.pack();
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

but this time all buttons print 3 even the button index is still 0,1,2, what is the reason?

Comment: why are you using an array `for(final int[] arr={0};arr[0]<3;arr[0]++){` ?

Comment: `arr[0]++` ... what is the value at `arr[0]` when the loop completes?

Answer (score 1):

After the loop ends, `i[0]` is `3`. The `ActionListeners` all hold a reference to `i` and will read the same value for `i[0]` which is `3`.

```
jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(""+arr[0]);
    }
});
```

If you want to correct this, assign the value of `i[0]` to a local final variable and us that for the output like:

```
for(int[] arr = {0}; arr[0] < 3; arr[0]++) {
    final int val = arr[0];
    ...
    jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("" + val);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second program, you are passing the same variable to all three buttons. And then you increment the value of the variable with each iteration. So the value gets updated for all three buttons.

Let me give you a simple example,

```
class Resource{
    int a = 10;
}
class A{
    Resource r;
}
class B{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Resource r = new Resource();

        A o1 = new A();
        o1.r = r;

        A o2 = new A();
        o2.r = r;

        o1.r.a = 20;

        System.out.println(o1.r.a);  // prints 20
        System.out.println(o2.r.a);  // prints 20 too
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to get the event source, and then you do not need final `int`

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
        jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            JButton jbutton=new JButton(""+ i);
            jframe.getContentPane().add(jbutton);
            jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
            jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JButton myButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    System.out.println(""+ myButton.getText());
                }
            });
        }
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }
```